# jQuery animate not scrolling properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a large container element to hold the smaller container element and its contents. I have my jQuery made to scroll on a button click but it is not working and I dont know why it isnt scrolling I had and alert in there to make sure it was working and that worked fine. This is the same code I used on a previous project and that works fine I cannot see where I am going wrong with this code.
Here is the jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#left-featured', function(event){
            $('#travel-item-container').animate({"scrollLeft": '+=-600px'}, 1000);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#right-featured', function(event){
            $('#travel-item-container').animate({"scrollLeft": '+=+600px'}, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the container and its elements:

```
<div class="travel-container">
                        <div id="left-featured">&lt;</div>
                        <div id="right-featured">&gt;</div>
                        <div id="travel-item-container">
                            <div class="travel-item">
                                <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
                                <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
                                <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
                                <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="travel-item">
                                <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
                                <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
                                <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
                                <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="travel-item">
                                <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
                                <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
                                <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
                                <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs some adjustment for the container, for example width, overflow, left property. This is how i did with adding a css rule.

```
#travel-item-container {  
   position:absolute; 
   top:30px; 
   left:20px; 
   width:30px; 
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the body that needs scrolling.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#left-featured', function(){
            $('html body').animate({"scrollLeft": -600}, 1000);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#right-featured', function(){
            $('html body').animate({"scrollLeft": 600}, 1000);
        });
```

```css
#left-featured
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#right-featured
{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.travel-container
{
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.travel-item
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="travel-container">
    <div id="left-featured">&lt;</div>
    <div id="right-featured">&gt;</div>
    <div id="travel-item-container">
        <div class="travel-item">
            <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
            <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
            <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
            <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
        </div>
        <div class="travel-item">
            <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
            <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
            <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
            <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
        </div>
        <div class="travel-item">
            <img class="travel-picture" src="Images/golf-course.jpg"/>
            <p class="travel-type">Golfing</p>
            <p class="travel-cost">$300</p>
            <p class="travel-title">Greensburg, IN</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```